# deduction proof

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, proof-theory

> Prove $p \wedge \neg p \vdash q$ for any propositional variables $p$ and $q$ without using disjunctive syllogism or excluded middle or $\neg$-elimination.

I can prove this easily using $\neg$-elimination: assume $p\wedge \neg p$ and $\neg q$. Then by $\wedge$-elimination, we have $p$ and again by $\wedge$-elimination, we have $\neg p.$ But then by $\neg$-elimination, we have $q$. However I'm not sure how to do it without using $\neg$-elimination. Will Peirce's law (i.e. $((A \to B)\to A) \to A$)) be useful?

> Clarification: $\neg$-elimination is defined as follows:
>   Let $\sum, A, B$ be formulas. Then if $\sum, \neg A \vdash B$ and $\sum, \neg A \vdash \neg B,$ then $\sum \vdash A$. Informally, it resembles the "proof by contradiction" method.

Comment: Terminology varies: what rule are you counting as not-elimination?

Comment: Details are needed... If you are working in a "constructive" setting, Peirce's law is not allowed: it is "classical".

Comment: If instead you are working in classical logic, you can prove it using Double Negation Elimination : $\lnot \lnot p \vdash p$.

Comment: Which inference rules are you allowed to use?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco the answers below are fine.

Comment: Please do not delete your post, as it makes it seem like you're hiding something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the rule of conjunctive simplification, we have $p$ and $\neg p$. Now, let $q$ be some proposition. Thus, we can use disjunctive addition to derive $\neg q \lor p$. By conditional exchange, we have $q \to p$. Finally, by modus tollens, we have $\neg q$

Comment: It's $\neg q \lor p$. I'm using the rule of conditional exchange, which states that $p \to q \iff \neg p \lor q$

Comment: The question states not to use disjunctive syllogism.

Comment: @lemontree I didn't use the rule of disjunctive syllogism. I used conditional exchange and modus tollens. Also, it seems that OP says the answer is fine in the comments.

Comment: Oh yes, you are of course right, I read your answer wrong. Sorry about that! I can't undo my unvite though unless the post is edited.

Comment: @lemontree No problem! I edited my post.